# Listbox with Expanders to another listbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox, expander

I'm trying to move an item from expander in listbox (keep the item there) and copy it to another listbox.

```
<ListBox Name="lbAvailableColumns" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Expander Header="Account" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  >
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListBox>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Account Is Locked Out"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Expiration Date"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Last Lockout Date"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Must Change Password"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Password Age(Days)"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Password Last Changed"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Password Never Expires"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Password Not Required"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Smart Card Required For Logon"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="User Cannot Change Password"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Username"/>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Header="Exchange" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
            <Expander Header="General" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
            <Expander Header="Group Membership" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
            <Expander Header="Organization" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
            <Expander Header="Other" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
            <Expander Header="Profile" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
            <Expander Header="System" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
            <Expander Header="Telephone" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
        </ListBox>
```

I'm trying to do the following, and am having a bit of trouble.

[image]

Trying to copy item from the expander listbox, to the visible columns listbox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the suggestions of [@Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett) I coded a complete example.

[image: Complete Example]

Source Code on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/a1300/TonyW_Expanders_Example)

Comment: Very nice! I did one of these as a custom control for work, but was badly rushed for time, so it's got a bunch of theme stuff specific to us baked into the template. No time to whip it into shape to post here. It does drag'n'drop between the lists, though. Getting that part right was a real laugh riot...

Answer (score 2):

I've written one of those things, but without the grouping into expanders. The grouping is a side issue if you do it right.

What you want to do is give your viewmodel two `ObservableCollection`s of some data item class, say `FromItems` and `ToItems`. Bind those two collections in XAML to the `ItemsSource` properties of the two `ListBoxes`.

The data item class could be a very simple quickie class with two properties (not fields): Say, `Name` and `GroupName`, both strings. Group by `GroupName`. [Here's a group template expander answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811787/424129), [here's how to do the actual grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2598299/424129) and set `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` on each `ListBox`.

The `>` button removes the left listbox's `SelectedItem` from `FromItems`, and adds it to `ToItems`. The `<` button does the reverse. You may not want to remove from `FromItems`, but then you'll have to be careful not to add them to `ToItems` twice.

Comment: Could you provide a very very small example of how to accomplish this, or perhaps a better link? This is helpful though as it stands.

Comment: I get the Observablecollection part, and I can set it up as such, but the second textbox will not have groups, just the item. So I'd like to go back and forth

Comment: @TonyW The grouping doesn't affect that -- it's a display thing done in the view. Grouped or not grouped, the viewmodel just has a flat ObservableCollection. The left/right arrow code is unaware of grouping

Comment: Ok, I have the first Observable collection setup with listbox1, and the grouping/sorting /w expander is working. So you're suggesting to add/remove from one Observablecollection, to the other? The only thing I worry about when doing that, is that if one expander only has one property, the group goes away.

Comment: @TonyW That's a good point. What about leaving all the items in the left pane, but graying out the ones that are in the right collection? You could do that with a datatrigger in the item template on the left collection, with a multibinding/multivalueconverter that takes the item A and the right-hand collection C2 and returns true if C2.Contains(A). You could put similar triggers on the buttons to enable/disable them appropriately.

Comment: I think i'll just add them to another observable collection and not remove them from the left listbox... easier that way lol :)